# Simple model of car-following as a linear system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling, simulation

I have the following simple model of car-following without delay:

$\ddot{x}_k(t)=\lambda[\dot{x}_{k-1}(t)-\dot{x}_k(t)],k=1,2,...,n. \quad\qquad(1)$

Where $\ddot{x}_k$ is the acceleration of the follower, $\dot{x}_{k-1}(t)-\dot{x}_k(t)$ is the relative velocity between the leading car and the follower car  and $\lambda$ is the sensitivity.

How can I express the equation $(1)$ as the next linear system of ODE

$\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)=A\mathbf{x}(t)+B\mathbf{\alpha}(t).$

Where $A$ is a matrix of $n\times n$ and $B$ is a matrix of $n\times m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get $\mathbf {\dot x}=A\mathbf x+\mathbf b$ where $A=λ(-I+S)$ with $S$ is the sub-diagonal matrix with entries $1$ on the first sub-diagonal. And $\mathbf b=λx_0(t)\mathbf e_1$.

Set $n=4$, write out the equations, especially the first one, and transcribe into matrix form to confirm that pattern.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{e}_1$ and for this case $\alpha(t)=\mathbf{b}$?

Comment: $\mathbf e_1$ is the first canonical basis vector, and yes, you can interpret it that way with $B$ the identity matrix.

Comment: Can I do a similar process if I had a car-follwing model with delay?

Comment: Yes, you can construct the matrices similarly. This is the trivial part in the delay-differential equation formulation.

Comment: The bang-bang principle for delay-differential equation system is similar that fot linear differential equation system?